# Messaging menu missing after few days of using ubuntu 10.10

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-10.10

I've recently installed ubuntu 10.10 on my Compaq Presario V3000. All was well - I had installed my favorite apps, updated the repos etc. But today, I find that the Messsaging Menu (the one with the envelope icon, which becomes green if you have a new chat/mail notification) is completely missing from my desktop panel ! This is very inconvenient for me, as I can no longer use the integrated Chat menu ! I've attached a screen of the panel as it is now .ie. without the messaging menu icon - can anyone please suggest how to bring it back on ?
Thanks

Comment: Does it come back if you reboot, or has it disappeared completely?

Comment: It had disappeared completely, but now its solved !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like it has just been removed form the panel. Right-click the panel -> Add to panel, and filter to find the 'indicator' applet, and add it.
[image]

Comment: Great !! In fact I discovered this on my own (deleted the entire panel first, then kept adding components till I got the one), but this deserves a vote-up and marked as the right answer !